# How to typeset \listof?

Tags: tocloft

In the example below, `\listof` is typeset like a chapter, font-size-wise. How can I change its display, for example to look like a section?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlistof
{foo}   % counter
{foo}   % file ext
{Foo}   % title 

\begin{document}

\listoffoo 
\chapter{Foo} % for comparison

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the title of `\listof...` in `\section*` style while still using `report` document class which provides a `\chapter(*)` command? Or perhaps you want a partial list instead? By default, `listof...` always uses the highest sectioning level under `\part`, and this do increases consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `tocloft` package looks to see if chapter is defined in your document class and formats accordingly. You could, after the `\usepackage` command lie to the package about whether you have chapter commands to get formatting like a section using the following

```
\makeatletter
\@cfthaschapterfalse
\makeatother
```

But as muzimuzhi Z commented on the question, it's not entirely clear what you're hoping to accomplish with this.

Comment: I just realize one needs package option `titles` for that to work.