# How to typeset \listof (revisited)

Tags: tocloft, report

I adapted the [first thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553871/how-to-typeset-listof) to account for the answer. While reduced, the font size of `\listof` still too big to be for what I want to accomplish, leaving the original question standing.

[image]

PS: I am aware there are packages dedicated to letters, but I use `\pkg{report}` as it gives more control.

```
\documentclass{report}
% \usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlistof
{foo}   % counter
{foo}   % file ext
{Encl.}   % title 

\makeatletter
\@cfthaschapterfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Dear Sir/Madam,

\lipsum[1]

Sincerely,
%\chapter*{Bar} % for comparison
\listoffoo 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Workaround: `\newlistof{foo}{foo}{\small Encl.}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `titles` option for `tocloft`.

```
% listoffontprob.tex  SE 555000

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft} % use this, not the titles option
\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlistof
{foo}   % counter
{foo}   % file ext
{Encl.}   % title 

\renewcommand{\cftfootitlefont}{\small\itshape} % change the foo title font

\makeatletter
\@cfthaschapterfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent Dear Sir/Madam,

\lipsum[1]

Sincerely,
%\chapter*{Bar} % for comparison
\listoffoo 

\end{document}
```

Use the `tocloft` provided method for changing the title font of the list.

Presumably you have set up for `foo` entries (see `tocloft` manual) and you can use `tocloft` methods for adjusting their appearance in the `foo` list to your needs.