# \listof<> without title

Tags: tocloft

In the past I asked how to [typeset the title of `\listofX`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555000/how-to-typeset-listof-revisited) from the `tocloft` package. I remember that since then, I had found a way to suppress the title altogether, such that I could use `\section{X}` in place of the title, which I find more convenient. Problem: I forgot how to do it, except it involved the `\makeatletter`+`\makeatother` idiom. What could that have been?

```
%\RequirePackage{background}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[pages=some, placement=bottom]{background}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553871/how-to-typeset-listof

%\newlistof[〈within〉]{〈entry〉}{〈ext〉}{〈listofname〉}

\newlistof{answer}{ans}{Answer}%\listanswername}

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{answer}
\par\noindent{Answer \theanswer. #1}
\addcontentsline{ans}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theanswer}#1}\par}

\makeatletter
\@cfthaschapterfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \section{Answer}
\listofanswer\par

\medskip

\answer{\lipsum[1][1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553871/how-to-typeset-listof

%\newlistof[〈within〉]{〈entry〉}{〈ext〉}{〈listofname〉}

\newlistof{answer}{ans}{Answer}%\listanswername

\newcommand{\answer}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{answer}
\par\noindent{Answer \theanswer. #1}
\addcontentsline{ans}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theanswer}#1}\par}

\makeatletter
%\@cfthaschapterfalse %Don't need 
\def\listofanswer{\@cfttocstart\@nameuse{cftmarkans}\@starttoc{ans}\@cfttocfinish}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Answer}
\listofanswer\par

\medskip

\answer{\lipsum[1][1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I remember the rhs was simpler, but this version works.  Would you know how to generalize it such that `answer` can be replaced by any other name?

Comment: @Erwann I am not quite understand your question, which answer you wanna replace? The answer word in command ‘\answer’

Comment: `\makelistof{answer}{ans}`-->`\listofanswer`.

Comment: @Erwann I am not sure, you wanna one `newlistof` command to define multiple lists?

Comment: I don't know how to express myself clearly, so I'm giving up. The existing answer suffices.