# How to reduce "new list of" character?

Tags: characters

how to reduce font size in "new list of""? and why when I insert "\listofmaps" does it appear red?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[label=corner]{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings

%titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%geometry
\geometry{a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.4cm,right=2.4cm,heightrounded}

%fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

%caption
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

%ulem
\normalem

%hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%newcommand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bigskip}{\qquad}
\setlocalecaption{italian}{listtable}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}

\newcommand{\listfirst}{Elenco Mappe}
\newlistof{maps}{frs}{\listfirst}
\newcommand{\first}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{first}
\par\noindent\textbf{first \thefirst. #1}
\addcontentsline{frs}{first}
{\protect\numberline{\thesection.\thefirst}#1}\par}

\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\  Fondamenti di Informatica}} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:}  \\ \textbf{Cognome:}  \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} } 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} }

\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listofmaps
\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
blablabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see anything red. Please add a screenshot showing the issue compiling *this* example document

Comment: Done! Latex Work, but it is red.check it.

Comment: "and why when I insert "\listofmaps" does it appear red?" That's just because your tex editor does not know your custom macro. This does not have any influence on latex. Either ignore the missing syntax highlighting or add the macro to your own .cwl file (I assume you use texstudio, correct?)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz exactly, but whit another command doesn't it

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yep, i use texstudio. how you do it?

Comment: Texstudio is able to parse if you define new commands with `\newcommand` etc., but it does not do this for new commands define via the detour of `\newlistof`

Comment: @LucaLongo See https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#cwl-guidelines for background information about cwl files. But again: it does not influence latex at all, it is just a cosmetic problem in the editor. I would not spend any time and effort in highlighting a macro which you only use once in the document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz well, thanks. Do you know how to change the size of the "Elenco Mappe" text in \newlistof?

Comment: @LucaLongo maybe try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553873/36296 but I don't know which other consequences the `titles` option for tocloft will have